# Find out when a member was added to an Active Directory group

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, directoryservices

I am getting info about users and groups from active directory. I am able to get various property values by way of an extension method.

```
public static string GetProperty(this Principal principal, string property)
{
    DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

    if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(property))
    {
        return directoryEntry.Properties[property].Value.ToString();
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

The problem I am facing is I need to get info that is buried deeper like **when** was a user added to a group? And I would like to be able to do this through C#. Is this possible? Possibly using these Security Events? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/174074

Using ASP.NET MVC, C#, `DirectoryServices.dll`

Comment: I do not believe that information is stored directly in AD in any queryable manner.  Your link refers to entries that would appear in the Security Event Log.

Comment: @stephen.vakil I think you're right about the info not being stored in AD directly. Since it is more like transaction data I am thinking it might be in the security events but I wasn't sure if those were easily accessible from c#

Comment: A user added flag doesn't sound like any property AD groups would have. Would pulling the list of users and then comparing to that list later on be possible? Or are you looking for some sort of built in notification that users were added?

Comment: @Demarini I am looking for something built in but it seems that such a thing doesn't exist. I am going to look into querying the security events for those codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your machines set to collect those events you can read the event logs to get the information you're looking for... I wrote this example to get `logoff` event. You can lookup the event IDs on MSDN.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ReadEventLogs
{
  class Program
  {
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Security", ".");

        foreach(EventLogEntry entry in eventLog1.Entries)
        {
          //Event ID 4624 LOGON
          //EVent ID 4634 LOGOFF
          if (entry.InstanceId == 4634)
          {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Message);
          }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

If no computer name or server is specified the event logs will be read from local machine `"."`

Comment: This got me going in the right direction. Unfortunately the group policy we have in place logs a lot of events so if I wanted to see something like when a user was added to a group, it might have happened log ago and the logs will have pushed that event out so it would not show that event anymore. But this would have worked.